# IDE for Web App development that keeps local code and Server code in Sync

Tags: php, javascript, ide

All my 12 years of experience I have used Vi/Vim for programming  because all IDEs are extremely bulky and causes the computer to run slow
But for developing Web Apps in PHP/javascript, the major pain point has been to make changes locally and sync it with the code in server.
I have been uploading files manually but soon I lose track of changes made in Server which needs to be submitted to my source code control system ( svn )

What would be the best IDE which is minimal and fast but has this functionality of allowing coding locally but allowing to upload the changes in the server or maybe even allow me to make the change directly only in server

Comment: You should push changes only to a public available server, if you are sure, that it works, and not, because you can.

Comment: Yes thats correct, having a test server is the ideal thing but sometimes it is require to make quick and obvious fix in a production server

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find the vast array of tools an IDE provides far outweighs the "bulkiness" of it.

As for your question, why not check-out your repository directly to the web-server, ensuring of course that **the web server itself is configured to NOT serve up anything in a `.svn` folder**?

Comment: That is what I had had setup, even with this I have to first make a commit, then login to server and then do an update. The issue is with this procedure I need to commit before trying it out and being sure that the change is the actual fix

Comment: @Raks, I know this is sort of off-topic, but why not have another server (also configured with SVN), or another web-site instance that you can checkout to FIRST to test the fix before checking it out on the live one?

Comment: Yes, those are the kinds of things I want to avoid doing, then I end up managing three instances, desktop, test-server, production-server, manage logins/security, preventing users for directly changing in the server, it will be like introducing more problems to solve one problem

Answer (score 1):

VIM can access files directly on the remove server, so you can edit it just in place like you have asked for it in part of your question (*"or maybe even allow me to make the change directly only in server"*):

```
vim scp://user@hostname.example.com//path/to/file.txt
```

The [path syntax can differ](http://tipotheday.com/2008/06/08/editing-remote-files-with-vim-and-scp/) depending what you need (username, port etc.).

Most editors and IDEs have support for something like that btw.

Comment: Does this command work on Windows XP platform. I tried it but there was no prompt for password. With this system will every character that I type will go to server or only when I save the file does it go to server. I do not want every character to be written to server, that would make typing very slow

Comment: I have no clue for windows, you might need to install a cygwin bash to make it working. this method will only transfer the files content to the server if you save it, not by typing.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the best IDE is still Unix,

Keeping your development code and production code in sync would be a nightmare! The whole point of having a seperate development environment is to stage changes to your live system! Indeed as the level of sophistication grows, there are usually an increasing number of separate environments between where you do your development and where the code runs.

The best way to deploy onto your live system would be by checkout from SVN (having checked in the code from your development env). If your production system can't access the respository, then checkout locally and use rsync to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

It may not satisfy the lightweight criteria, but Aptana Studio does allow you to automatically keep local and remote code in sync, and to edit files directly on the remote server.